# Simultaneous Total Differential Equations 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

To Solve : $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{x^2-y^2-z^2}=\frac{dy}{2xy}=\frac{dz}{2xz} $

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can solve
$$\frac{dy}{2xy}=\frac{dz}{2xz}\ ,$$
that gives you
$$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dz}{z}$$
and thus
$$y(z)=\frac{y_0}{z_0}z=:K z\ .$$
Now you have to solve
$$\frac{dx}{x^2-(K+1)z^2}=\frac{dz}{2xz}\ ,$$
$$d(x^2)=\frac{dz}{z}(x^2-(K+1)z^2)\ .$$
$$z\frac{zd(x^2)-x^2dz}{z^2}=-(K+1)zdz\ .$$

If you put
$$w:=\frac{x^2}{z}\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad dw=\frac{z d(x^2)-x^2dz}{z^2}\ ,$$
you get 
$$dw=-(K+1)dz\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad w=w_0-(K+1)(z-z_0)\ .$$
$$x(z)=\sqrt{\frac{x_0^2}{z_0}z-\left(\frac{y_0}{z_0}+1\right)z(z-z_0)}\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

(possible?) Hint:

$$\frac{dy}{2xy}-\frac{dz}{2xz}=0$$

$$\frac{dy}{dz}=\frac{y}{z}$$

From this you can obtain y as a function of z.

Comment: Thanks .. I also need to make a second connection like this .. where there would be no y or z .. for the second simultaneous equation ..